# Сокращение конструкций выборки

Tags: javascript

**Здравствуйте!**

Вот у меня давно возникал вопрос, но я как-то (и почему-то) не предавал ему особой важности. Вопрос заключается вот в чем: допустим, есть такая конструкция:

```
switch(dig%10)
    {
        case 1: ender='ие';break;
        case 2:case 3:case 4:
        case 5:case 6:case 7:
        case 8:case 9: ender='ий';break;
        ...
        }
```

Выглядит это по-нубски и путано. Хотелось бы это дело распутать. Можно ли каким-либо образом сократить количество кейсов? Промежуток указать, например?

Comment: А зачем 2,3,4,5,6,7,8 отдельно проверять? Просто если остаток равен 1 или 9 то break. Еще непонятно что с нулем делать? В общем случае можно бинарным деревом снизить крупное ветвление c O(n) до O(lg(2,n)) если пополам просто делить.

Comment: @igumnov, что? Тут для каждого остатка свое назначение. Поэтому вашим способом здесь, к сожалению, не отделаться...

Comment: можно - default

Comment: @asen Так добавьте в 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 выражнеий каких-нибудь, а то с ходу непонятно. Типа case 2: alert('Назначение 2')

Comment: @Palmervan, да, можно конечно же, но все-таки бывают случаи, когда, скажем N различных диапазонов, содержащих, как минимум по M значений(кейсов) должны делать что-то определенное...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такого ещё не предлагали

```
var d = dig%10;
switch(true) {
  case (d == 1): ender = 'ие'; break;
  case ((d >= 2) && (d <= 9)): ender = 'ий'; break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: оригинально

Comment: Интересно, похоже на Select ... Case Is из VB.

Comment: Именно то, что нужно, король JavaScript`а =) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

если default, предложеный [[@Palmervan](/users/3526/palmervan)](/users/3526/palmervan), по каким-то сокральным причинам не подходит, то можно делать нечто вроди такого:

```
if([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].indexOf(dig%10) > -1){
   ....
}
```

ещё вариант использовать для этого хэши(для длинных диапазонов быстрее):

```
hash = {
   '1':1,
   '2':1,
   '3':1,
   ...
}
```

и использовать всё в том же if

```
if(hash[dig%10]) { ... }
```

но оба варианта для более сложных значений, которые возможно будут дополняться во время работы, а не для двух вариантов как у вас!

> скажем N различных диапазонов, содержащих, как минимум по M значений

вот это уже более подходщий случай использование вышесказаных техник

- [Determining Objects in a Set: Examples in JavaScript](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2012/08/determining-objects-in-a-set-examples-in-javascript.html?utm_source=javascriptweekly&utm_medium=email)

Comment: @Spectre, спасибо! Как понимаю, стандартных средств для этого не существует в JS...жаль. Но я привел всего лишь пример, или вы хотите, чтобы я продемонстрировал полный пример, содержащий десятки вложенных кейсов?

---
Все вышеприведенные техники мне, к счастью, знакомы. Я же лишь интересовался стандартными способами, основанными на уровне самого JS.

Comment: нет-нет, просто приведённый пример кода не совсем раскрывает суть вопроса

>Я же лишь интересовался стандартными способами, основанными на уровне самого JS.

так это и есть уровень js

Comment: @Spectre дабы сделать код еще более не нубским - первую конструкцию можно сократить :)

    if(~[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].indexOf(dig%10)){
        // ....
    }

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю предназначения этого кейса, но если по коду:

```
switch(dig%10)
{
    case 1: ender='ие'; break;
    case 2:case 3:case 4:
    case 5:case 6:case 7:
    case 8:case 9: ender='ий'; break;
}
```

то все многообразие вариантов можно свести, к:

```
switch(dig%10)
{
    case 1: ender='ие';break;
    case 0: break;
    default: ender='ий';break;
}
```

`dig%10` даст цифру от `0` до `9`. Для `1` задан единственный вариант `ender='ие'`. Для `0` вариантов нет. Во всех остальных случаях `ender='ий'`.

Answer (score -1):

Для наглядности, красоты и не запутанности, лучше делать наглядную выборку! Ведь такая конструкция проста как 2х2! Если как-то извращаться, делать "гениальные" конструкции, которые могут вроде как на пару строчек кода уменьшить, то можно запутаться и запутать того кто твой код читать будет. 
Весь принцип таких выражений - создание ветки на каждый особый случай. Это что касается общего вопроса.

А вот что касается примера, то он действительно не красивый. В некоторых случаях можно и `if` использовать, различные предварительные вычисления и т.п. Все зависит от текущей задачи. Так что я думаю что лучше не лезть в непонятные дебри и использовать давно придуманные и зарекомендовавшие себя приемы :) ПАТТЕРНЫ читай, и много ответов найдешь ты!

Comment: @Антон Мухин - в конце предложения не хватило только ***юный подаван*** :D

Comment: @Аsen , я так полагаю, ты МОЖЕШЬ объяснить почему это вызвало у тебя такую реакцию. Или это просто так?